# How to expose alpha parameter in Seaborn displot

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

Is there anyway to expose `alpha` parameter in `seaborn` `displot` function?
Here is some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

A = np.random.standard_normal(20)
B = np.random.standard_normal(20)
C = ['cat1','cat2',]*10
z = pd.DataFrame({'col1':A,'col2':B,'col3':C})
sns.displot(data = z, x = 'col1',hue = 'col3')
```

[image]

I tried using `hist_kws` but it doesn't seem to have it.
I want the histograms to overlap but I want them to be transparent.

```
sns.displot(data = z, x = 'col1',hue = 'col3',hist_kws= {'alpha': 0.1})
'Rectangle' object has no property 'hist_kws'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the histograms overlapping, but transparent, you should use `alpha = 0`. I think the `hist_kws` is valid for the older distplot. Is this what you are looking for? Just be aware that alpha=0, will not allow you to differentiate between the two plots. Maybe alpha=0.1 would help....

```
A = np.random.standard_normal(20)
B = np.random.standard_normal(20)
C = ['cat1','cat2',]*10
z = pd.DataFrame({'col1':A,'col2':B,'col3':C})
sns.displot(data = z, x = 'col1',hue = 'col3', alpha=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't even think to use `alpha` directly in `displot`. I didn't see it in the documentation so assumed it was not accessible directly.